# Serving static files through apache

Tags: apache-2.2, python, mod-wsgi, flask

I am new to the whole mod_wsgi and serving files through apache. I am really comfortable with flask but this is something i can't get my head around. I did the hello-world program and successfully displayed hello world! Now i wanted to display a image file. So I updated my hello-world.py to:

```
from flask import *
yourflaskapp = Flask(__name__)

@yourflaskapp.route("/")
def hello():
    file="203.jpg"
    return render_template("hello.html",file=file)
#   return"HEY"
if __name__ == "__main__":
    yourflaskapp.run()
```

my directory structure is something like:/var/www/hello-world

```
/hello-world
    test.py
    yourflaskapp.wsgi
    /static
        -203.jpg
    /templates
        -hello.html
```

My template is simple, hello.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><title>hi</title></head>
<body>
<img src="{{url_for('static',filename=file)}}"/>
</body></html>
```

and my apache conf file is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     WSGIDaemonProcess yourflaskapp
     WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/hello-world/yourflaskapp.wsgi
     Alias /static/ /var/www/hello-world/static
     Alias /templates/ /var/www/hello-world/templates
     <Directory /var/www/hello-world>
            WSGIProcessGroup yourflaskapp
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
     </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/hello-world/static>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/hello-world/templates>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
     LogLevel warn
     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
 </VirtualHost>
```

Though when i open the browser and head to my ip, it doesn't show the image file. What am i doing wrong? Is there any other approach i should follow? and if anyone could recommend any good links from where i can understand working with flask+mod_wsgi+apache2.

Comment: "it doesn't show the image file" <-- What does it show?

Comment: @ChrisS it just shows an icon where i added the image tag.